# Checking Struct fields Type using reflect

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I am trying to check struct fields using  Go `reflect` package. I have tried it in many ways and found two possible ways. But in the second way i have mentioned in below, complex or custom types can not be checked (example uuid.UUID). Only types that are included in [reflect.Kind](https://golang.org/src/reflect/type.go?s=8483:8497#L222). Is there any other possible way to check custom type (example uuid.UUID) using `reflect` ?

First Way   [run here](https://play.golang.org/p/DjYp0H_kRbU)

```
 package main
 
 import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
 
    "github.com/google/uuid"
 )
 
 type Object struct {
    A string
    B int64
    C uuid.UUID
    D int
 }
 
 func main()  {
    obj :=Object{}
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
    for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++{
        switch {
        case typ.Field(i).Type == reflect.TypeOf(""):
            fmt.Printf("type of field %s is %s \n", typ.Field(i).Name, reflect.TypeOf(""))
 
        case typ.Field(i).Type == reflect.TypeOf(int64(0)):
            fmt.Printf("type of field %s is %s \n", typ.Field(i).Name, reflect.TypeOf(int64(0)))
 
        case typ.Field(i).Type == reflect.TypeOf(uuid.New()):
            fmt.Printf("type of field %s is %s \n", typ.Field(i).Name, reflect.TypeOf(uuid.New()))
 
        default:
            fmt.Printf("default: type of field %s is %v \n", typ.Field(i).Name, typ.Field(i).Type)
        }
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
type of field A is string 
type of field B is int64 
type of field C is uuid.UUID 
default: type of field D is int
```

Second Way - replacing switch as below [run here](https://play.golang.org/p/UDuNz6oNzjv)

```
        switch typ.Field(i).Type.Kind(){
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Printf("type of field %s is %s \n", typ.Field(i).Name, reflect.String)

        case reflect.Int64:
            fmt.Printf("type of field %s is %s \n", typ.Field(i).Name, reflect.Int64)

        default:
            fmt.Printf("default: type of field %s is %v \n", typ.Field(i).Name, typ.Field(i).Type)
        }
```

Output:

```
type of field A is string 
type of field B is int64 
default: type of field C is uuid.UUID 
default: type of field D is int
```

Comment: You are looking at `Kind`, which, for uuid, is reflect,Array

Comment: Is there any problem with your first method, or does it work?  Also hint about second method: You're switching on the "kind" of the field, not its "type".

Comment: yes, Then i can not differentiate kind "array"  with UUIDs

Comment: @HymnsForDisco it is working. But i am not confident with the method, because i have hard coded values in the `switch`. I need to find a standard kind of way to do this.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "hard coded values"?

Comment: for string -> TypeOf(""), for int64 -> TypeOf(int64(0)) 
like this

Comment: If using reflect, then this is required. To make it look more standard I'd just recommend replace `""` with `string("")` and `uuid.New()` with `uuid.UUID{}`